# A study is to be performed to determine a certain parameter in a community. From a previous study a standard deviation of 46 was obtained......

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

A study is to be performed to determine a certain parameter in a community. From a previous study a standard deviation of 46 was obtained. A sample error of up to 4 is to be accepted. How many subjects should be included in the sample of study at 95% level . of confidence?

Comment: What do you know? What have you tried?

Comment: Probably the reason for the down-vote is that this is phrased as if it's a copied homework problem. You have to at least show that you understand what you're saying.

Answer (score 0):

Use the equation E = z*SD/sqrt(n) rearranged to solve for n.
First determine the z score for a 95% confidence level.